# Trying to whitelist a 'more' specific NGINX location BUT returns 404 instead

Tags: nginx

I have the following in my nginx configuration:

```
        # /abx/xyz/ 
        location /abc/xyz/ {
                allow 5.194.207.217;
                deny all;

                proxy_pass http://proxy-server/;
        }

        location /abc/ {
                proxy_pass http://proxy-server/;
        }
```

Whenever I access `/abc/xyz` it returns a `404 Not Found` error.
How can I make `/abx/xyz` work correctly?

Comment: What is your goal? To redirect everyone from abc/xyz and abc/ fo your proxy servers main page directly? What is the current config files server name? A full config file would be appreciated.

Comment: These are inside a server block. I got it. I was missing an /xyz at the end of the first proxy_pass line.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing appending `/xyz` to the proxy_pass URL.

So the correct answer would be as follows:

```
        # /abx/xyz/ 
        location /abc/xyz/ {
                allow 5.194.207.217;
                deny all;

                proxy_pass http://proxy-server/;   # <<< REMOVE THIS LINE
                proxy_pass http://proxy-server/xyz;   #  <<< .. AND CHANGE IT TO THIS LINE      
        }
```